# In scala 3, how instance of an opaque type can invoke method defined on its backed type

Tags: scala, scala-3, opaque-types

According to the book *Advanced Programming in Scala 5th edition* wrriten by Martin Ordersy

> Note that adding an upper bound to an opaque type doesn’t act like the extends keyword does when defining a class. In particular, an opaque type does not inherit the interface of its upper bound. For example, although you can pass a NonEmptyString where a String is required, you cannot invoke
> methods declared on class String on a NonEmptyString:

```
object NonEmptyStrings:
  opaque type NonemptyString <: String = String
  object NonEmptyString:
    def apply(S: String): NonEmptyString = 
      require(s.nonEmpty)
      s
    def from(s: String): Option[NonEmptyString] = 
      if s.nonEmpty then Some(s) else None
……………………………………
// in a different .scala file
import NonEmptyStrings._
"hi".charAt(1) // i
NonEmptyString("hi").charAt(1)
1 |NonEmptyString("hi").charAt(1)
  |ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
  |value charAt is not a member of
  |NonEmptyStrings.NonEmptyString
```

> The only methods you will be able to invoke on an opaque type are those defined on Any and those added via any extension methods defined for the opaque type, even if the opaque type is given an upper bound

But when I coded like that, no exception occured.The `NonEmptyString("hi").charAt(1)` runned normally and the result can be printed to `i`

But when I code like that, no exception occured.The `NonEmptyString("hi").charAt(1)` run normally and the result can  println into console showing `i`.

My practice is not like the book predicted.

Comment: How did you call the method? Was it inside the very place which defined opaque or somewhere else?

Comment: Care to provide a reproducer of the behavior you mention? BTW, I guess you simply passed such `NonEmptyString` to a method that expected a `String` and inside that you can, of course, call `charAt`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I tried to call the method in a different .scala file, which perform as same as I call the method in the same file where I define opaque type

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez My reproducer is just like the code  above。
My practice support your point , I do invoke the `charAt` moethod succefully, which voilet the offical book _advanced programming in scala_. The book told me the expecting result is an exception, that is the place confused me

Comment: I can confirm: even from a different package, it is possible to call `NonEmptyString("hi").charAt(1) ` (using Scala 3.3.1).

Comment: If one outcomments the `<: String` part, one gets the `value charAt is not a member of` error: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rPN9iDSOSHGMJYxdyB0qmg - with `<: String`, it compiles. To me, it very much seems like there is an error in the book (or: a bug in the compiler if one assumes that the book is in line with the language specification).

Comment: Well, to be fair, I don't understand why the behavior the book mentions is desired in any way. I just have never used opaques since I found the whole feature utterly unusable.

Answer (score 0):

After a short discussion with one of the book's authors, I confirm this is incorrect or outdated, and should be fixed in the next edition.